# Earth Quake Question Logarithmic Type Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An earthquake off the coast of Vancouver Island was measured at 8.9 on the Richter Scale
and an earthquake off the coast of Alaska was measured at 6.5. How many times more intense, to the nearest whole number, was the earthquake off the coast of Vancouver Island than the one off the coast of Alaska?

Comment: I was trying to read of Wikipedia to solve this program. 
Approximate Magnitude Approximate TNT for
Seismic Energy Yield Joule equivalent

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated or at least a how I could start?

Comment: so 6.5=log(I/S) ? what is s or I

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $M=log(I/J)$, where M is the magnitude of the quake, I is the earthquake's intensity and J is the intensity of a standard earthquake.

**Hint #2**: Try converting it to exponential form: $10^{M}$=(I/J), because $\log_a x=b\implies a^b=x$.

Since you know know M, evaluate $10^{M}$. That value is equal to (I/J), so then you find (I/J) for each of the respective quakes. Hopefully that should help!

Comment: So for Vancouver I know 8.9 so that would be J? and Alask is 6.5=J

Comment: I don't know though the magnitude which is the unknown variable :/

Comment: Read the question again: the magnitude of both earthquakes is given. (8.9 for Vancouver and 6.5 for Alaska)

Comment: but then I still have an unkown varoable

Comment: The standard intensity (J) will cancel out.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Normally, you would just take the ratios and be done but since earthquake intensities are reported on the logarithm scale- you need to take the ratio of the respective exponential values.

Comment: can you start me of Sujan gave the the formula M=log(I/J) I think j is 8.9

Comment: The value of $J$ does not matter as it will cancel out. You will see if you write out the relevant equations.

Comment: Is no one able to help me ? please